# font weight bold not support in opera (my opera version is 12.02)

Tags: css, opera, font-face

font-weight: bold property not support in IE, Opera, Safari, Chrome. Is there any way to make font bold format here I'm using TradeGothic Custom font and I have installing this font at website loading time.

I've written following line of code:

```
<span style="font-family:TradeGothic; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal;">Surface or DIN rail mtg enclosed temperature controlle</span>
```

Please resolve this problem. Thanks !!

Comment: Opera does support bold font, but most likely you've loaded only the regular version of your custom font and the bold one is missing. You have to load that as well.

Comment: Please stop using presentational tags like `<b>` and `<center>`. Also how did you "install" that font ?

Comment: Please provide more information, especially the `@font-face` rule.

Answer (score 4):

Of course `font-weight` is supported in Opera. But if you only include your regular font and not the bold version too, you are not guaranteed to have crossbrowser ( and more important cross-OS! ) results.

Also - are you sure, you mean `Trad Gothic` and not `Trade Gothic` - fonts with whitespaces also should always be quoted: `"Trad(e) Gothic"`.

Comment: ya, you are right, this is TradeGothic

Comment: On Windows 7 at least, Opera 12.02, as well as other browsers, applies algorithmic bolding when bold is requested for and the font specified is not available as bold. This could be construed as a bug, but it is common browser behavior.

Comment: @jukka this is what i mean with inconsistent results - the calculated bolding might differ between browsers and OS and in comparison between browsers lead to "hey, this one didn't do it right"-effects.

Comment: @Christoph, the problem description says that bold is not supported in opera (as per the heading) or browsers in general (as per message text). This suggests that no bolding is applied. This is possible if the font is declared as bold in `@font-face` but isn’t bold